# Add cck field as scoring factor to drupal standard search

Tags: 6, search

So, by default there are four scoring factors in drupal:

- relevance of keyword
- recency
- number of comments
- number of page views

I'd like to be able, to control relevance of specific cck-fields.
In my case, i've got a cck field (computed field), where all relevant search-data is getting summed up.

I'd like to be able to give this special field a higher relevancy to the search results than anything else.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Implement [hook_update_index](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_update_index/6) in a way that calls [search_index](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_index/6). The source code of `search_index` tells you how the `$text` argument is analyzed. From a quick look at the source, I would wrap the field content in `<h1>` tags. Not that the string only applies to searching, not to rendering. So it does not need to represent the actual structure of the node.